# How to know the character string to be specified in local of @font-face only with Windows7 function

Tags: windows-7, fonts, css

The `local` function requires a postscript name or a full font name as an argument:

> For OpenType and TrueType fonts, this string is used to match only the *Postscript name* or the *full font name* in the *name table* of locally available fonts. <sup>[ref](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-fonts-3/#font-face-rule)</sup>

However, when I opened the font file in Notepad, I couldn't find these names or even the name table. Is there a way to view the name table in the font file using only the functions provided in Windows7?

Answer (score 0):

The Postscript name of a font was not intended for use by end users, and so you won't see it exposed anywhere in Windows 7 or in Windows 10.

If you need to find the Postscript name of a font, then you should use a font inspection utility that is intended for more specialized user scenarios. Here are a couple of free utilities that you could use:

- [SIL ViewGlyph](https://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=ViewGlyph_home) — see View Names in the Options menu
- [BabelMap](https://babelstone.co.uk/Software/BabelMap.html) — see Font Information in the Fonts menu